# Getting parsing error using fill css in react

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, svg

```
 <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 64 64">
      <g id="flat">
        <path
          d="M43,43H38.952a2.3,2.3,0,0,1-2.273-1.926h0a4.816,4.816,0,0,0-3.642-3.962,4.728,4.728,0,0,0-5.695,3.834l-.021.128A2.3,2.3,0,0,1,25.048,43H21a6,6,0,0,0-6,6h5v3h8V49h8v3h8V49h5A6,6,0,0,0,43,43Z"
          style={{fill:#746250}}
        />
```

It says Unexpected digit after hash token highlighting this: #

What is correct way of using fill css in react? I'm trying to import svg file. Other alternative ways also appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try giving fill in path tag directly instead of adding it in style

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 64 64">
      <g id="flat">
        <path
          d="M43,43H38.952a2.3,2.3,0,0,1-2.273-1.926h0a4.816,4.816,0,0,03.6423.962,4.728,4.728,0,0,0-5.695,3.834l-.021.128A2.3,2.3,0,0,1,25.048,43H21a6,6,0,0,0-6,6h5v3h8V49h8v3h8V49h5A6,6,0,0,0,43,43Z"
          fill="#746250"
        />
```